# DJI Drone ROS connection with Remote Mavproxy

Tags: ros, dji-sdk

I want to connect DJI Drone having companion Computer RasperryPi installed DJI Onboard-SDK-ROS.
Can I connect ROS Node which is running in RasperryPi (Computer A) via Mavproxy which is installed in Remote Computer (say Computer B) ? Assumption Both Computer are in same network.

Comment: Simple answer: Yes. More complicated answer: You're asking the wrong question, see [ask].

Comment: It is correct and valid question. See Mohammad Ali's answer.

Answer (score 1):

MavProxy only works on flightcontrollers with Mavlink communication Protocol.

Also Mavproxy is not a ROS Node. ROS Node for Mavlink Communication protocol is **MAVROS**.

What You are asking can be done if companion raspberry pi Can send Mavlink data on the network Other than that you can use DJI_SDK for ROS which you can find On their [GitHub](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS)

**EDIT 1**
After Searching a little found out an exception that is DJI Matrice and manifold flightcontroller can communicate over mavlink You can see [DJI Wiki](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/github-platform-docs/ROS_Example/ros_dji2mav_0.2.1_package.html)

Comment: @Mohammand Ali. it is correct that I will have to use DJI sdk for Ros in companion Computer which is hosted in GitHub. Now my question is that does DJI_SDK for ROS  expose IP and Port which can we configure in remote MAVPOXY or Ground controller system ?

Comment: exposure of IP and  Port are One thing and 2 systems talking to each other in the same language is another. I believe some DJI drones can send data over TCP/IP Like Tello and you can assign That port to Mavproxy (Or Mavros) but I don't think you can communicate correctly with Drone

Comment: Thank. DJI-ROS node is able to control DJII Drone with MavLink commands. Actually I want below setup - 
1. Install DJI-MAVROS sdk into companion computer --- Can be done.
2. send MavLink command from same companion computer using Terminal via MAVROS command --- Can be done 

In above assumption we can create a MAVROS node in companion computer which can talk to DJI Drone if we send MAVLink commands. Now my query is that Dose the MAVROS node exposes some port to connect with it  from remote ground controller system / Mavproxy?

Comment: You can do such a task in 2 way in Mavros:
1:set GCS IP and Port Number So You can connect with any flightcontroller like QgroundControl,etc (This Use Plain IP Forwarding Just Like Mavproxy)
2:use Built In ROS Network to issue commands to MAV using Topics And Services (This is the way to go if You are using Your own Code to control The Drone)